# Swift: Reuse code passing class to parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to reuse code, so I created `redirectToTabBarControllerChild`

```
func redirectToTabBarControllerChild(storyboardName: String, tabBarIndex: Int, segueID: String, viewController: UITableViewController) {
    let storyboardMain = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboardMain.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = tabBarIndex
    let navigationViewContrller = tabBarController.childViewControllers[tabBarIndex] as! UINavigationController
    let currentViewContrller = navigationViewContrller.childViewControllers.first as! viewController
    currentViewContrller.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: nil)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

The last parameter I would like to pass `ProfileViewController` for example. But I have an error in this line: `let currentViewContrller = navigationViewContrller.childViewControllers.first as! viewController`

`Use of undeclared type viewController`

Does anyone know how I could do it?

Comment: because it's an object, not a type. Try `viewController.self` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigationController?.childViewControllers` is an `array` of `UIViewControllers`. You´re getting the `first` property which means you need to cast it to `as! UIViewController` which will force cast it and it will not be an optional anymore.

What you want to do is to cast it to a `UITableViewController`, so do it like this:

```
if let vc = navigationViewContrller.childViewControllers.first as? UITableViewController {
    // Will succeed if the first is of type UITableViewController
    // Use vc in here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it is no reusable, because if instead use UIViewController I'm use UITableViewController for example, how can I pass this in parameters?

Comment: Great, glad to help @VictorMendes

Answer (score 0):

Replace viewController to UITableViewController